# Flatlist simulating different pages

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have to build 5 pages but as they have all the same layout I want to use a flatlist to populate the fields, my doubt us vary basic, I read the documentation and had problems to fully understand, here is my code

```
const DATA = [
  {
    picture: '../../Components/Images/wellbeing.png',
    text1: 'Get weekly overviews and find',
    text2: 'out whats impacting your health',
    text3: 'and wellness',
    percent: 20,
  },
];

const Item = ({picture, text1, text2, text3, percent}) => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Image source={require({picture})} style={styles.image} />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.text_field}>
        <Text style={styles.textContent}> {text1} </Text>
        <Text style={styles.textContent}> {text2} </Text>
        <Text style={styles.textContent}> {text3} </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HabitTracking')}>
          <ProgressCircle
            percent={{percent}}
            radius={30}
            borderWidth={3}
            color="#3399FF"
            shadowColor="white"
            bgColor="blue">
            <Icon name="arrowright" size={25} color="white"></Icon>
          </ProgressCircle>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
    );
```

I'm having trouble on how to populate this in the class, here is what I have so far

```
const Wellcome = () => {
    const renderItem = ({picture, text1, text2, text3, percent}) => (
        <Item picture={Item.picture}
        
        />
    );
  return (
    
  );
};

export default Wellcome;
```

am I doing everything wrong?
please let me know if you need any further information

Comment: you have some basic error. Here is const renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <Item picture={Item.picture} />
    )

Answer (score 0):

```
const renderItem = (item) => (
        <Item picture={item.picture} />
);
```

and call renderItem in your render method

```
...
{renderItem(item)}
...
```

where item looks something like...

```
{
  picture: 'something',
  text1: 'something',
  text2: 'something',
  text3: 'something',
  percent: 'something'
}
```